# geometric distribution properties

Tags: probability

In the book "probability and computing" they are saying the following lemma :

$\Pr[X=n+k|X>k]=\Pr[X=n]$

I have tried to do the following :

$\Pr[X=n+k|X>k]=\frac{\Pr[X=k+n\cap X>k]}{\Pr[X>k]}=\frac{\Pr[X\ge k+n]}{\Pr[X>k]}=\frac{\sum^\infty_{j=k+n}{(1-p)^{j-1}p}}{\sum_{j=k+1}^\infty{(1-p)^{j-1}}p}=\frac{(1-p)^{n+k}}{(1-p)^{k+1}}=(1-p)^{n-1}=\sum^\infty_{j=n}(1-p)^{j-1}p=\Pr[X\ge n]$

so I have got this formula ! so what's correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is incorrect because $\{X=k+n\cap X>k\}\neq \{X\ge k+n\}$. Instead $\{X=k+n\cap X>k\}= \{X= k+n\}$ and what the book says is true.

Comment: correct ! thank you !!